# Using time field in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have got a database field containing only a time, it's declared in my migration as

```
$table->time('time')->default('00:00:00');
```

Now I want to add a number of seconds to this field using Eloquent, doing something like:

```
$activetime->time->add(new DateInterval('PT5S'));
```

(where $activetime is a object of a Eloquent model)

First try on this I got

```
Call to a member function add() on string
```

So obviously I have to tell Eloquent that this is not a string but a time. The closest I have got is putting it in protected $dates in the model, but then instead I get

```
Unexpected data found.
```

I suspect this is because it isn't really a date but only a time, but I can't seem to find much information about how to handle times. Is there any way of solving this or would I be better off using something else, like dateTime or timestamp (or even an integer for amount of seconds)? What I DO want to record is a users amount of active time for a given date, so for that purpose time seems like the natural choice...

Comment: What do you need the time to be casted to? Do you have a Time object?

Comment: Format the $activetime->time and then add your seconds.

Comment: if your model don't have any other date field then you may add the following to the model. `public $timestamps = false; protected $dateFormat = 'H:i:s'; protected $dates = [ 'time', ];`

Comment: Well, I have the built in timestamps fields (created_at, updated_at), I guess they would be affected by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Laravel reads `time` database type as just a `string` and you are expecting a `DateTime Object`.

Add this to your Eloquent model:

```php
public function getTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return new \DateTime($value);
}
```

You can also cast your `time` to `DateTime Object` using [Laravel Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), but you'll have to append some date to your time, because Laravel is expecting correct format

Comment: Wouldn't this only solve the reading of the value? I'd have to do the reverse operation for writing, right?
Anyway, I think I'm resorting to simply saving active time as seconds instead, and doing the pretty date formatting upon output instead. Seems easier since I'm missing nice builtin functions for time handling.

Comment: @DanielMalmgren yes, this is just for the reading of the value. You can also play around with `setTimeAttribute` to satisfy your needs